# How to handle, when tkinter window gets focus

Tags: python, tkinter, focus, protocols

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()
w.protocol('WM_TAKE_FOCUS', print('hello world'))
mainloop()
```

It prints `hello world` only once, and then it stops working. No more `hello world` Basically `WM_TAKE_FOCUS` does not work.

Comment: ***"Basically WM_TAKE_FOCUS does not work."***: That's not true! You have to use: `.protocol('WM_TAKE_FOCUS', lambda: print('hello world'))` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can bind a function to the `<FocusIn>` event. When you bind to the root window the binding is applied to every widget in the root window, so if you only want to do something when the window as a whole gets focus you'll need to compare `event.widget` to the root window.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def handle_focus(event):
    if event.widget == root:
        print("I have gained the focus")

root = tk.Tk()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()

root.bind("<FocusIn>", handle_focus)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just for those searching, `"<FocusOut>"` does do the opposite of `"<FocusIn>"`.

Comment: If `<FocusIn>` is the first event, can you use it to give another window focus and it will block say a button press that gave our window focus in the first place?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: yes, can switch the focus to some other widget when it gets a `<FocusIn>` event.

Comment: @BryanOakley OK. But let's say user clicked "Close" button which gave window focus. If I lifted another Window and gave it focus, would the "Close" click be ignored?

Comment: @BryanOakley Disregard last question. The answer below by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7324618/bimal-paudel solved my problem.

Comment: This does not seem to work when switching focus from one `Toplevel` to another.

Comment: @martineau: I don't know what you mean. If another Toplevel widget gains the focus, the event will still trigger appropriately.

Comment: I tried using `<FocusIn>` in a situation where each `Toplevel` has bound `<Key>` events to it's own handler, and I'm trying to figure out a way to get those events to switch where they go when I click on one of the `Toplevel` instances to activate it.

Comment: @martineau: if you put that in the form of a question, I'm sure we can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

"Note that WM_SAVE_YOURSELF is deprecated, and Tk apps can't implement WM_TAKE_FOCUS or _NET_WM_PING correctly, so WM_DELETE_WINDOW is the only one that should be used".
Here's [a link](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8454/)!
If you need to keep tkinter focus all the time:

```
w.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```

does a pretty good job.

Comment: I need to do something, when window gets focus.