# Protocols in tkinter in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new in Python and I want to use protocols like `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`, `WM_TAKE_FOCUS` and `WM_SAVE_YOURSELF`. I have found an example of `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` which is clear enough to understand. But I want to understand the rest two protocols. What do they do?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()

def on_closing():
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I read in another question that `WM_TAKE_FOCUS` not working correctly. That same question gives an alternative way to accomplish what `WM_TAKE_FOCUS` would do.
If it worked correctly, `WM_TAKE_FOCUS` would happen when the window is in focus. If you don't know what focus is, you can ask me.

[How to handle, when tkinter window gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613191/how-to-handle-when-tkinter-window-gets-focus)

---

`WM_SAVE_YOURSELF` is deprecated, but here are a couple of useful links that may help.

https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.protocol-method
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_(computer_storage)